# GIT:In the merge folder it is creating ~head file

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

While doing merge using sourceetree in the merge folder (in file system) I noticed it creating two files called `~head` and `~branch`.  Why are these files being created?
Those files are not created for all the merging files only for few files it's creating.

Please help me on this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? This always happens to you? Did you have merge conflicts during the process?